# DynamoDBMapper Annotations. OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have an Employee Table (i.e. an Item) in Amazon DynamoDB. The Attributes of that table are {employee_id, name, manager_id}

The class is represented in Java using:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    private String employeeId;
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> subordinates;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(final String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
    public String getIntegerAttribute() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
        return subordinates;
    }

    public void setSubordinates(List<Employee> subordinates) {
        this.subordinates = subordinates;
    }
}
```

Given a following Org Chart

```
A
-B
 |
  --- B1
 |
  --- B2
-C
 |
  --- C1
```

If I request employee A, B and C should be loaded a subordinates of A. B1 and B2 should be loaded as subordinates of B. C1 should be loaded as a subordinate of C.

The above functionality is easy to achieve using Hiberate's @OneToMany annotation. What's the recommended way to achieve this in Dynamo?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `@OneToMany` in terms of Dynamo? Do you expect these items to map to objects in other tables or do you just want `Map` behavior?

Comment: And by `Map` I just mean nested map attributes

Comment: Hi Mike, I expect the class fields to map to objects in other tables (just like I had it above). That is I do not want Subordinate employee IDs, I want the subordinate employees.

Comment: Since DynamoDB is non-relational you won't be able to achieve the mapping natively with DynamoDB without managing the relationships yourself or coming up with a data model that is supported in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

One to many is natively supported by the HashRange schema of DynamoDB.

You can create your table like this:

```
Subordinate-Table (for storing relationship)
HashKey: EmployeeId (for manager)
RangeKey: EmployeeId (for subordinates)

Employee-Table (for storing employee info)
HashKey: EmployeeId
Attribute: Name
```

For your sample org chart, your Subordinate-Table will look like this:

```
Hash: A Range: B
Hash: A Range: C
Hash: B Range: B1
Hash: B Range: B2
Hash: C Range: C1
```

To get all subordiates of manager A, you just need to do `dynamdob.query(HashKey=="A")`

Regarding your question about getting the employee data directly without an extra call to the Eployee-table: You can merge the two tables above into one table:

```
Company-Structure-Table:
HashKey: EmployeeId (manager)
RangeKey: EmployeeId (subordinates)
Attribute: Name (name of the subordinate)
```

Regarding your second question about avoiding manually getting all the subordinates below a manager (searchi recursively), here is my thought: DynamoDB gives you a database primitive that you can build application on top of. You want to design your schema to make the primitive very efficient. You can build your own logic on top of DynamoDB. Recursively searching for all the employees below a manager is one of those application-specific logic. You can easily built it and parallelize it. I don't think the mapper lib includes it.

Comment: Hi Erben, Your solution is to query the subordinates table using the manger id (A in this example) to get the subordinate employee ids, and then look up those subordinates in the employee table. What about sub-ordinates of sub-ordinates. This is a lot of manual work that I'd want to avoid. I am wondering if there is  a way to model entity relationships in Dynamo the way Hibernate does it. i.e. can DynamoDBMapper be enhanced to achieve what I am talking about.

Comment: just confirming that this functionality currently isn't built into DynamoDBMapper

Answer (score 0):

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Table1")
public class ItemDTO  {...}
```

itemDTO is an instance of ItemDTO and represents an item that exists in 'Table1' and 'Table2', but the itemDTO has been changed. Now I want to save those changes in both tables.

```
# update of the itemDTO in 'Table1'
mapper.save(itemDTO)
# create TableNameOverride config for 'Table2'
TableNameOverride table2Override = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride('Table2')
# update of the itemDTO in 'Table2' by passing new DynamoDBMapperConfig w/ table2Override
mapper.save(itemDTO, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(table2Override))
```